# What did Thanos mean when saying "This day extracts a heavy toll"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, avengers-infinity-war

What does Thanos mean when he says "This day extracts a heavy toll" upon meeting Doctor Strange on Titan in *Avengers: Infinity War*? I used Google Translate and it didn't really mean anything in my language.

Comment: Hi! This is really a language question, not specific to the movie, but it will also be closed on ELL. Have you checked a dictionary for the definitions of "extract" and "toll"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an English language comprehension question.

Comment: @Tetsujin not sure it's off topic, it's more focused on the context, not pure meaning.

Comment: I'm not seeing it as anything other than 'I don't understand what this sentence means'. It's antiquated English, but it's still perfectly comprehensible English to a native. That makes it nothing more than a comprehension question in my mind.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's mostly about the language, but it still depends on the scene. I think OP is trying to understand why Thanos said that at that time, to Strange and what caused him to say it... What's the valuable thing he lost, how much it means to him etc.. sure, I'm also voting to close this because it's 95% about the language.

Comment: How is this a language question. The OP is asking to explain the dialogue. He is a non-native english speaker who did some research whether the dialogue has some obvious meaning. It is still valid question here. The OP may have forgotten that Maw was an important ally to Thanos & hence say the line.

Comment: So far there have been 4 edits to this question, each trying to push it further towards being plot-based rather than simply not understanding the phrase in English. Right now I think we've gone 2 edits past 'changing the OP's intent'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was said as part of a sentence:

> Thanos: I take it that Maw is dead? This day extracts a heavy toll.

Also, shortly before that scene, Thanos

> Has to sacrifice Gamora to get the Soul stone

So the toll is losing people he trusted and cared about a lot.

Comment: And don't forget that shortly before this scene, he'd had to kill a certain other someone who was close to him.

Comment: @F1Krazy was it on the same day? I need to watch the movie again. :)

Comment: IIRC, *Infinity War* more or less takes place entirely in one day.

Comment: Infinity war that lasts a single day... kinda ironic. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard He arrives at Titan right after that.

Comment: @AJ thanks, I forget things like that after short time... will mention this in the answer.